# How to use SQL for crosstab query in Microsoft Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

Have a school DB (School_Data), a student DB (Student_Data) then a series of DB tables for Class IX (Student_Data_XI), Class X, Class XII and Class XII as student move from Class IX to Class XII. Can create a crosstab query for Class IX to Class XII but indiviudally but Want to create a crosstab query where the total number of students for a particular school show Class IX to Class XII accessing the four class DBs.

Row headings: SchoolID, School Name and AllocatedYr (e.g. 2013-14, 2014-15, etc)
Column headings: No. of students (Class IX), No. of students (Class X) till Class XII.

The result would look something like this

SchoolID   SchoolName   AllocatedYr  Class IX  Class X   Class XI  Class XII

1234       Any School   2013-14         30         28      25         20

Having difficulty using crosstab with multiple tables to count multiple students for each class.Thanks.

Comment: You should probably provide a query example, and format your question better - clarity is everything.

Comment: You seem to have a bad design. Why have a new table for class when you can have a column?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework... the Microsoft Support Sites, for Office, are plethora of knowledge. Even the MSDN sites, are easy to read, and include multiple examples.

[Crosstab Queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8)